# Custom Instagram Login Page in Swift

Tags: swift, authentication, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I want to built an **custom login page** for Instagram and not using the WebView. Is there any way possible to do the authentication in the background and getting the **Client ID** & **Access Token**!

Also, Right now I am passing the predefined ClientID and hence only I can login into Instagram.

[Webview of instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSjEz.png)

Comment: Take a look at developer notes https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah I've seen that but they specified that for getting the access_token we need to have client ID.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not make your own custom login page to login with Instagram. You can only do it by hitting `authURL` provided by them. And user needs to login to their login page with `URL`.

Comment: Sir I've seen some Android Application that uses custom login page to login into Instagram. If possible please have a look at this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=insta.vidmateapp&hl=en_IN

Comment: Not sure how they did it but it should not happen because that you will have you will have user id and password of that Instagram account and it will be very easy to hack. Probably that's my thought.